# Session Storage vs Local Storage if data is needed for backend frequently

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 6.

**Problem**

1. Database has 10 cards. Card ID 1, 2, 3, ... 10
2. Front end allows User to select 2 cards out of 10 cards (e.g. Card 5 and Card 6)
3. The system would select 5 cards randomly
4. If cards selected found in the 5 cards, they will be placed first in the return array of records (e.g. if Card 5 and 6 are found, the sequence would be 5, 6, 1, 3, 4)
5. Front end would display the cards in the right sequence

**Current Solution**

I currently store card selected on Local Storage as string `5,6`. However, this is not ideal cos I need to constantly pass the local storage to Rails backend.

I thought of session storage, but not sure if it's the better implementation.

**Criteria**

I don't want to store in database, because there is no user login. I don't mind if the session gets expired, but data should persist for a period of time. Page refresh should not remove the data.

**Question**

What is the most elegant way to solve this - user select on front end, Rails backend take the selected to manage the sequence? I don't want front end to do rearrange because it's slow and there will be flicker).

Comment: Storage is if you need this info to persist beyond a page refresh or beyond browser sessions. Is that a requirement? If not, you could consider using a cookie as it will automatically be attached with each request.

Comment: @Nick Yes, data must persist beyond a page refresh or beyond browser sessions.

Comment: Okay, then local storage is probably a good bet. Session storage will clear when the current tab is closed. You could persist the info to local storage and then whenever making a request you could attach the information in the body of the request. If you don't like explicitly attaching on every request you could set a cookie whenever the page loads or whenever the card selection is changed.

Comment: @Nick Changed my storage from Local Storage to Cookies. Thanks for the suggestion.